Is it possible to integrate feature extraction within Core ML model/pipeline?
I have a Core ML model (.mlmodel) which I then can use in the Swift code using the Core ML framework to make predictions. However the feature extraction is also happening in this code. I currently use .mlmodel which was created by transforming an sklearn model using coremltools, but also know how to create .mlmodel using CreateML.
Is it possible to make feature extraction as a part of the model (or a pipeline), so that the rest of the code can stay the same if the model changes?
This means that in the code example below there would be no need for the extractFeatures functions as the .mlmodel would contain that within and it would only need to receive the input.
I have tried to create a pipeline using sklearn Pipeline, but it wouldn't transform to .mlmodel because it doesn't support custom preprocessing functions as part of the pipeline.
import CoreML

// Function to extract and calculate features
func extractFeatures(bedrooms: Double, size: Double, age: Double) -> [Double] {
    let additionalSpace = 0.1 * size
    let totalSize = size + additionalSpace
    let totalRooms = bedrooms + 1
    return [totalRooms, totalSize, age]
}

// Function to predict house price using the ML model
func predictHousePrice(bedrooms: Double, size: Double, age: Double) -> Double {
    let model = try! HousePricePredictor(configuration: .init())
    
    let features = extractFeatures(bedrooms: bedrooms, size: size, age: age)
    
    let inputArray = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [3], dataType: .double)
    for (index, feature) in features.enumerated() {
        inputArray[index] = NSNumber(value: feature)
    }
    
    let prediction = try! model.prediction(input: HousePricePredictorInput(features: inputArray))
    return prediction.price
}

// Usage example
let price = predictHousePrice(bedrooms: 3, size: 2000, age: 10)
print("Predicted house price: \(price)")

